# How to solve the problem that postion sticky did not work in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, css-position

The Header is using Vuetify <v-app-bar>
But I need to make the filter column fixed while scrolling prodcuts.

```
<template>
   <v-container fluid>
      <v-col>
        <v-col style="position: sticky; z-index:2; position: -webkit-sticky; top:0; position:fixed;">...</v-col>
      </v-col>
   </v-container>
</template>
```

Browser: Chrome

Additional info:
https://uxdesign.cc/position-stuck-96c9f55d9526

I've read this article but still couldn't figure it out.

Comment: https://elad.medium.com/css-position-sticky-how-it-really-works-54cd01dc2d46
This one is good as well but I still couldn't fix it.

Comment: I've changed the position by adding " top:50px" to find the column then manipulate.
If anyone has other solution please leave in the comment

Comment: Should your first `v-col` be `v-row` as you have a `v-col` nested in another `v-col` in your example?

Comment: This might help https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#sticky_positioning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vuetify 2.6 has a [banner](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/banners/#slots) component that has a sticky attribute e.g.

```
<v-banner single-line sticky>Content here</v-banner>
```

But this might not be a suitable component for you... I don't know what content you want in there for example...

But otherwise it should be pretty simple to 'build your own'. Have a look at the docs on [MDN here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#sticky_positioning) for further explanation. But essentially it's as simple as the following HTML/CSS taken verbatim from MDN:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

dl > div {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 24px 0 0 0;
}

dt {
  background: #b8c1c8;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #989ea4;
  border-top: 1px solid #717d85;
  color: #fff;
  font: bold 18px/21px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2px 0 0 12px;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: -1px;
}

dd {
  font: bold 20px/45px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 12px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

dd + dd {
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <div>
    <dt>A</dt>
    <dd>Andrew W.K.</dd>
    <dd>Apparat</dd>
    <dd>Arcade Fire</dd>
    <dd>At The Drive-In</dd>
    <dd>Aziz Ansari</dd>
  </div>
  <div>
    <dt>C</dt>
    <dd>Chromeo</dd>
    <dd>Common</dd>
    <dd>Converge</dd>
    <dd>Crystal Castles</dd>
    <dd>Cursive</dd>
  </div>
  <div>
    <dt>E</dt>
    <dd>Explosions In The Sky</dd>
  </div>
  <div>
    <dt>T</dt>
    <dd>Ted Leo &amp; The Pharmacists</dd>
    <dd>T-Pain</dd>
    <dd>Thrice</dd>
    <dd>TV On The Radio</dd>
    <dd>Two Gallants</dd>
  </div>
</dl>
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice! I try to make the filter sticky below the header when users scroll down to see through the products!